# Cannot optimize hexa aqua Cu(II) and Fe(III)

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, gaussian, geometry-optimization

I try to optimize very simple systems - hexa aqua Cu(II) and hexa aqua Fe(III) - in Gaussian 16. The inputs are provided in the end of the post. Unfortunately, the geometry optimization never finishes as the water molecules keeps oscillating around the metal center. What to do?

Thanks

`Cu_II.inp`

```
# opt freq M05/genecp scrf=smd

Copper

2 2
 Cu                -1.28477910    0.71194762    0.00000000
 O                  0.54522090    0.71194762    0.00000000
 H                  0.86522090   -0.16280021    0.23241394
 O                 -1.28477910    2.54194762    0.00000000
 H                 -0.63246994    2.86194762   -0.62744941
 O                 -1.28477910    0.71194762    1.83000000
 H                 -2.17186239    0.53227224    2.15000000
 O                 -3.11477910    0.71194762    0.00000000
 H                 -3.43477910    0.49890795   -0.87966704
 O                 -1.28477910   -1.11805238    0.00000000
 H                 -1.68807007   -1.43805238   -0.81028168
 O                 -1.28477910    0.71194762   -1.83000000
 H                 -0.68938242    1.29220858   -2.31000000
 H                 -0.99684089    1.57002197    2.15000000
 H                  0.86522090    0.94804515   -0.87376081
 H                 -1.78485813   -1.43805238    0.75440106
 H                 -3.43477910    1.58028145    0.25533576
 H                 -2.15432081    2.86194762   -0.25119160
 H                 -1.88017579    0.13168665   -2.31000000

H O 0
6-311+G(d,p)
****
Cu 0
SDD
****

Cu 0
SDD
```

`Fe_III.inp`

```
# opt freq M05/genecp scrf=smd

Iron

3 6
 Fe                -1.71203729   -0.44477496    0.49027634
 O                 -1.71203729    1.38522504    0.49027634
 H                 -1.51209094    1.70522504   -0.39245888
 O                 -1.71203729   -0.44477496   -1.33972366
 H                 -2.19853442   -1.20800530   -1.65972366
 O                  0.11796271   -0.44477496    0.49027634
 H                  0.43796271   -1.31171025    0.75032096
 O                 -1.71203729   -0.44477496    2.32027634
 H                 -2.00815096   -1.30006246    2.64027634
 O                 -1.71203729   -2.27477496    0.49027634
 H                 -2.49501382   -2.59477496    0.03624136
 O                 -3.54203729   -0.44477496    0.49027634
 H                 -3.86203729    0.46013048    0.50888105
 H                 -2.57648159    1.70522504    0.75848532
 H                 -2.12976559    0.35815907   -1.65972366
 H                  0.43796271   -0.23651257   -0.39053396
 H                 -0.82327976   -0.27357317    2.64027634
 H                 -0.92734321   -2.59477496    0.03921626
 H                 -3.86203729   -0.91333984    1.26464509

H O 0
6-311+G(d,p)
****
Fe 0
SDD
****

Fe 0
SDD
```

Comment: I don't know if Gaussian actually uses this information in the geopt by default, but you could try `geom=connectivity` and specify that your waters are bound to metal center, as described [here](https://gaussian.com/geom/)

Comment: It does. Even with, it fails. Contrary, without SCRF it optimize. Though, I need to use SMD solvent.

Comment: Is the starting geometry you using from a successful optimization? It may help to start from an optimization that succeed without solvent or with a different solvent model (e.g. PCM) or with a different level of theory. (If these are also things you already tried, enumerating in your question what you have tried to fix the problem or versions of the calculation that you know work/don't work will avoid answers/suggestions that you have already tried).

Comment: Right now, I try to optimize in `CPCM`. Hard to say what I have already tried, because there was a lot of these. I tried `M052X`, `M05`; checked `6-311+G(d,p)` and `GENECP` as in the input; tried with vacuum (suceeded! but moving to solvent again failed). I also lowered maxstep, enforced `calcfc`, `recalcfc=10`, or even `calcall`. Used `nosymm`. I think all of these in more or less combined manner.

Comment: Oh, and I tried to lower `maxstep`.

Comment: That's all good to know, those are probably all things I would suggest trying if you hadn't yet. 

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352340918314483?via%3Dihub) performed optimizations of $\ce{Cu(H2O)_6}$ in Gaussian and gives example input files in the SI, but it looks like they didn't include solvent effects.

I think your best bet would be to try different functionals to see if you can get a solvent  converged geom. Ideally functionals that are fairly different from M05 just to check if the functional is the culprit, e.g. M06L, wB97xD, B3LYP

Comment: Our Gaussian chat room might be of interest.

Comment: @Tyberius That's the point ! In solvent it optimizes... Will try some other just to check, yet M05 is the one I must use.

Comment: @NikeDattani Gaussian Chat Room? What is that?

Comment: @farmaceut the site has chat rooms for specific topics, e.g. the [Gaussian room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64028902#64028902). These are useful for extended discussions as comments can be tough to find later. I mentioned the paper more so to say that while there are papers on this topic, none that I have found address your problem. For the other functionals, they can help to indicate if there is some issue with M05 for this system, but they also may get you an initial guess geometry that is close enough to the minimum so the M05 optimization won't drift away.

Comment: I have just tried with Dunning's basis set but also failed... Certainely, the issue is with SMD.

Comment: Just a guess: The problem can be that introducing solvent effects sometimes create PES with abrupt changes: when it creates different cavities, as the geometry changes during optimization, suddenly different part of the cavity can disappear. If you really need this particular energy, why do not just scan it around the vacuum optimal geometry. With such high symmetry, it is not particularly expensive.  Note: this basis set combination is very inaccurate as MSwat already mentioned

Comment: @Greg
"If you really need this particular energy, why do not just scan it around the vacuum optimal geometry. With such high symmetry, it is not particularly expensive" == What do you exactly mean to do? Scan each geometrical property one by one?............... "Note: this basis set combination is very inaccurate as MSwat already mentioned"==I can shift entirely to M05/6-311+G(d,p)... but first need to be able to optimize it

Comment: Maybe you could use solvent accessible surface (SAS), or solvent excluded surface (SES)? They generally remove discontinuties in the PES that arise from solvation.

Comment: @farmaceut It is unclear what symmetry you work with, but you should have no more than 2-3 relevant parameters. If the opt cannot find the minimum in this space, you can still sample it and make a reasonable estimation for the structure and energy of the minimum. It is not clear what your goals are, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Th geometry at the start in `Th` point group otherwise its just mangling and cannot smoothly decrease;
2. Optimiazation in `z-matrix` coordinates; in redundant or cartesian it just doesn't account for the very small changes in atom coordinates and exaggerate them so far beyond the threshold;
3. `nosymm` keyword to prevent Gaussian from refining the provided geometry, as it tends to change move slightly water hydrogens at the start of the job
4. `int=ultrafine` combined with `maxstep=1` seems to be  crucial as well because, as I suppose, the PES is very flat.

In my case this lead to the situation when system **DID** optimize but with a single imaginary frequency of over 200i.

The solution for that was rerun using the same input file but the optimized  geometry with a single imaginary frequency along with the changing of convergance criterion to `verytight` as well as `opt` into `fopt`...

...I should actually know because reading Gaussian's manual it is stated that "*[Regarding  optimization in`z-matrix` coordinates system...] In this case, the keyword `FOpt` rather than `Opt` requests that the program verify that a full optimization is being done (i.e., that the variables including inactive variables are linearly independent and span the degrees of freedom allowed by the molecular symmetry).*"

Answer (score 2):

For [my paper from 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ct800277a) I started from the coordinates [by Pierloot and co-workers](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2353829). They used C(i) symmetry for their CASPT2 study of Fe(II)(H2O)6, which you might do as well as a starting point.

Second, because you're using a metagga-hybrid functional you will need to use at least an UltraFine grid (or probably better). In particular, I would not use M05 for these systems, but use a more relevant one like r2-SCAN-D4, one of Grimme's composite ones, or simply the OPBE functional as was used in [1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ct800277a).

Third, I would not use a combination of a huge basis set on O/H and an almost minimal one with ECP on the metal. This is bound to go wrong. It is better to use a consistent basis set on all atoms, e.g. def2-tzvp minimally.

Comment: I need energies at M05/6-311+G(d,p) for both systems. That's why, I stick to that.